# Adding client remote interface class to classpath on run time and lookup

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, rmi

This is my code:

```
public class MyLoader  extends URLClassLoader
{
public MyLoader  (URL[] urls)
    {
        super (urls);
    }
    public void addFile (String path) throws MalformedURLException
    {

        addURL (new URL (path));
    }
}
```

First I load the interface class:

```
URL urls [] = {};
MyLoader cl = new MyLoader (urls);
cl.addJar("jar:file:///c:/jars/myjar.jar!/");
cl.loadClass ("lebj.interfaces.RRServices");
//no fails here
```

Then I try to lookup and obtain the RemoteInterface:

```
 Object home = loginInitialContext.lookup(JNDI);
EJBHome theHome = (EJBHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(home, EJBHome.class);
EJBMetaData md = theHome.getEJBMetaData();          
EJBHome homeInterface = md.getEJBHome();

 md.getRemoteInterfaceClass();// ERROR
```

This is the error:

```
weblogic.utils.AssertionError: ***** ASSERTION FAILED *****[ Unable to load remote interface: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lebj.interfaces.RRServices ]
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.EJBMetaDataImpl.getRemoteInterfaceClass(EJBMetaDataImpl.java:115)
```

(If I add jar manually to eclipse project classpath then it works)

Comment: very *intelligent*  to downvote a comment without  commenting

Comment: Try it without the `jar:` and the trailing `!/`.

Comment: Please provide the rest of the stack trace. You need to use that classloader for everything, including the class that executes the lookup code. Just calling `cl.loadClass()` doesn't accomplish anything especially when you throw away the result.

Comment: there is nothing more in the stack trace, following 2 lines are from my code from above,

Answer (score 0):

Adding a classloader and loading a class via it does not constitute 'adding client remote interface class to classpath [at] run time', *unless* all the classes that use that remote interface are loaded via the same class loader.

Comment: So my option is to use SystemClassLoader?

Comment: Or the part of my answer after 'unless'.